# html-emails - Email sending won't work if I add an image

Tags: html-email

We send several emails through our system (Java / Spring backend but not sure what we use for email sending).

All emails work fine, but this particular one. I have this tiny snippet in the email

```
<div style="border-bottom:1px solid #cdcdcd;float: left;width:100%">
   <span style="float:left;width: 45%;">
      <a href="redirect to my clients website">
         <img src="fullPathToTheImageInOurSever" style="padding: 5px; width:54%;">
      </a>
   </span>
</div>
```

If I comment out the img tag the email will get sent, no issues. If I add it back, no email..

The odd thing is that I have this very same snippet with this image in all other emails and they work just fine.

Am I missing something regarding how HTML works in emails?

Comment: That doesn't make sense. Is the path being generated dynamically and some exception / error is being raised? Check the logs

Comment: Does the server reject the email as spam?

Comment: It's not dynamic, just hard coded path. I'll ask my sysadmin to check if the server is rejecting.